# Simple_html_dom getting the image + the URL only

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get the image url and the a href only of each post using **[simple_html_dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net)** this is all that I have been able to figure out so far.

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
foreach ($html->find('div[class="media-body"]') as $div) {
echo $div . '<div style="width: 100%; height: 0px; color: #eee;"></div>';
}; // Something.
```

If you look above this pulls my entire `media-body` class like it's suppose to how ever I am trying to achieve an end result of it only pulling the content displayed below.

```
<a class="pull-left" href="http://www.example.com">
   <img width="64" height="64" src="http://placehold.it/64x64" class="media-object">
</a>
```

This is the content which is inside of my current `media-body` class that has the url and the image that I am trying to get.

```
<div class="media-body">
    <div class="media">
      <a class="pull-left" href="http://www.example.com">
       <img width="64" height="64" src="http://placehold.it/64x64" class="media-object">
      </a>
    <i>
       <a class="media-heading" href="http://www.example.com">
       Example Artist - Example Song Name.
       </a>
    </i>    
      <a href="http://www.example.com">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Download</button>
      </a>
    <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Then you should be `find`ing `div class="media"`. not `media-body` no?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky This does not work when you filter for `foreach ($html->find('div[class="media"]') as $div)` it pulls everything inside of `media` class not just what we're looking for.

Comment: @Slacks. image is okay what about url there are 3 urls... so which url you want to get. the url which contains image...??

Comment: @TintuCRaju the part I commented out above the `media-body` content is what I am trying to get the one with `<a class="pull-left"></a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
    include('simple_html_dom.php');

    $html = '<div class="media-body">
        <div class="media">
          <a class="pull-left" href="http://www.example.com">
           <img width="64" height="64" src="http://placehold.it/64x64" class="media-object">
          </a>
        <i>
           <a class="media-heading" href="http://www.example.com">
           Example Artist - Example Song Name.
           </a>
        </i>    
          <a href="http://www.example.com">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Download</button>
          </a>
        <br>
        </div>
    </div>';

    $html = str_get_html($html);
    foreach ($html->find('div[class="media-body"] a[class="pull-left"]') as $div) {
       echo $div . '<div style="width: 100%; height: 0px; color: #eee;"></div>';
    };

?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much my friend!